# Log different levels to multiple files Python

Tags: python-2.7, logging

I would like to have 2 loggers, one that logs a summary of what my code is doing, and one that logs specific details. I would like to have the loggers write to different files in different locations as well. However my loggers currently write to the same file.

```
# Create MAIN Log
logging.basicConfig(filename=main_log_path,level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
# Create Details logger
logging.basicConfig(filename= detailed_log_path,level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

main_logger = logging.getLogger('Log_Summary')
detailed_logger = logging.getLogger('Detailed_Summary')

main_logger_handler = logging.FileHandler(main_log_path)
main_logger.addHandler(main_logger_handler)

detailed_logger_handler = logging.FileHandler(main_log_path)
detailed_logger.addHandler(detailed_logger_handler)

main_logger.info("this is the main logger")
detailed_logger.info("this is the detailed logger")
```

Comment: That's because your file handlers are both setup with `main_log_path`.

Answer (score 1):

```
detailed_logger_handler = logging.FileHandler(main_log_path)
detailed_logger.addHandler(detailed_logger_handler)
```

Change the `main_log_path` to something else. Right now both the loggers point to the same file. You need different paths to log to different files.